# "fuser -cu /mount_point" result shows many processes?

Tags: mount

I wanted to change the mount point name from /hdd_ext to /data1. So I checked what processes are using that directory. (ref : https://www.golinuxcloud.com/how-to-change-mount-point-name-in-linux/)
But when i do `fuser -cu /hdd_ext/', I see so many somethings as below. They don't look like process IDs. I closed all the apps and opened only one terminal. How can I make those disappear??

> ckim@ckim-ubuntu:~$ fuser -cu /hdd_ext/ /hdd_ext:
> 2584rce(ckim)  2590rce(ckim)  2592re(ckim)  2601re(ckim)  2618re(ckim)
> 2633re(ckim)  2640re(ckim)  2687re(ckim)  2707re(ckim)  2730re(ckim)
> 2734re(ckim)  2768re(ckim)  2781re(ckim)  2872re(ckim)  2886re(ckim)
> 2895re(ckim)  2896re(ckim)  2899rce(ckim)  2900rce(ckim)
> 2907rce(ckim)  2912rce(ckim)  2916rce(ckim)  2990re(ckim)
> 3037re(ckim)  3041re(ckim)  3042re(ckim)  3044re(ckim)  3046rce(ckim)
> 3058rce(ckim)  3063rce(ckim)  3068rce(ckim)  3077rce(ckim)
> 3085rce(ckim)  3095rce(ckim)  3099rce(ckim)  3104rce(ckim)
> 3113rce(ckim)  3119rce(ckim)  3126rce(ckim)  3133rce(ckim)
> 3137rce(ckim)  3139rce(ckim)  3172re(ckim)  3174re(ckim)  3175re(ckim)
> 3176re(ckim)  3177re(ckim)  3179re(ckim)  3182re(ckim)  3185re(ckim)
> 3186re(ckim)  3187re(ckim)  3192re(ckim)  3195re(ckim)  3199re(ckim)
> 3200re(ckim)  3210re(ckim)  3211re(ckim)  3221re(ckim)  3222re(ckim)
> 3286re(ckim)  3287re(ckim)  3288re(ckim)  3296re(ckim)  3309re(ckim)
> 3313re(ckim)  3393re(ckim)  3432re(ckim)  3588rce(ckim)  3591re(ckim)
> 5237rce(ckim) 12764rce(ckim) 48534re(ckim) 48541rce(ckim)
> 48546re(ckim) 48645re(ckim) 48654re(ckim)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are processes. The manpage on fuser explains the `ce` and `cre`:

```
c      current directory.
e      executable being run.
f      open file. f is omitted in default display mode.
F      open file for writing. F is omitted  in  default  display
       mode.
r      root directory.
m      mmap'ed file or shared library.
```

so the `e` states "executable being run"

> I closed all the apps and opened only one terminal.

That still leaves all the systemd services. If you want to find the source: use `ps -ef | grep {pid}` I expect those all to end up to the same type of event: a systemd service.

> How can I make those disappear??

It is likely mounted from `/etc/fstab` and after you edit that the obvious thing to do is a reboot. That will kill all connections to the mount so there should be no need.

Comment: OK, I read from the ref link that I have to check before the umount command. Is it ok to edit fstab and just reboot? (the link showed umount and mount without rebooting..). I'll try it tomorrow. thanks!

Comment: Yes. If nothing else needs to change that is fine.

Comment: Just a minuite ago, I edited the fstab file, (and made new mount point ealier), and dit umount /old, and mount /new, and it just worked. I should have checked the 'fuser' command (to see if it worked with all the user processes) but I didn't check. Thank you.